# Getting error when i click a link repeatedly. (Hibernate and Spring 3)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.killerlinks.dao.LinkformDaoImpl.getCategory(LinkformDaoImpl.java:42)
    com.killerlinks.service.LinkformServiceImpl.getCategory(LinkformServiceImpl.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.killerlinks.controllers.CategoryController.getCategory(CategoryController.java:43)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:XE

    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.killerlinks.dao.LinkformDaoImpl.getCategory(LinkformDaoImpl.java:42)
    com.killerlinks.service.LinkformServiceImpl.getCategory(LinkformServiceImpl.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.killerlinks.controllers.CategoryController.getCategory(CategoryController.java:43)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.33 logs.
```

This is the error i am getting when i click a link repeatedly, again if i refresh the link it is working fine. This is error is coming now and then.

This is my hibernate configuration file.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.killerlinks.model.Reg</value>
                <value>com.killerlinks.model.Linkform</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Should i add any hibernate properties ?

Comment: could it be that you are exhausting the pool of connections?

Comment: @Uncle Iroh Yeah may be . . . How to configure that ?

Comment: It's probably configured in your spring config.  <bean id="dataSource"...<property name="maxActive" value="24" />...